# CSV dialect in pandas DataFrame to_csv (python)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, export-to-csv

I'm happy to use `csv.Dialect` objects for reading and writing CSV files in python. My only problem with this now is the following:

- it seems like I can't use them as a `to_csv` parameter in `pandas`
- `to_csv` and `Dialect` (and `read_csv`) parameters are different (eg. `to_csv` have `sep` instead of `delimiter`)... so generating a key-value parameterlist doesn't seem to be a good idea

So I'm a little lost here, what to do.

What can I do if I have a dialect specified but I have a `pandas.DataFrame` I have to write into CSV? Should I create a parameter mapping by hand?! Should I change to something else from `to_csv`?

I have `pandas-0.13.0`.

---

Note: `to_csv(csv.reader(..., dialect=...), ...)` didn't work:

> need string or buffer, _csv.writer found

Comment: Do you wish to use one of the standard `csv` dialects (e.g. `excel`), or are you writing your own custom dialect?

Comment: @MatthewJeppesen standard `csv` dialect with the delimiter `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a CSV reader, than you don't need to also do a `pandas.read_csv` call. You can create a dataframe with a dictionary, so your code would look something like:

```
csv_dict = # Insert dialect code here to read in the CSV as a dictonary of the format {'Header_one': [1, 2, 3], 'Header_two': [4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(csv_dict)
```